# How to limit the number of instances created from a particular function

Tags: javascript

I recently came across a discussion which I found is amusing and have come here for better understanding.

Suppose I have a function named testFunc

```
function testFunc(){
 // Logic
}
```

now I can initialize n number of instances using new

```
var t1 = new testFunc();
var t2 = new testFunc();
.
.
.
.
```

is there a way where I can limit the number of instances that can be created from the the particular function?

Comment: What's the reason behind this? Why would you want to limit?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Learning Javascript. So trying all possibilities that come to mind.No business reason

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not?

```js
var instances = 0;
function testFunc() {
  if (instances >= 2) {
    throw "instance limit exceeded";
  }
  instances++;
}

var t1 = new testFunc();
console.log('t1 ok');
var t2 = new testFunc();
console.log('t2 ok');
var t3 = new testFunc();
console.log('t3 ok');
```

Comment: Instead of a using a global variable, it may be nice to use a static property attached to the function.

Comment: @BorisGuéry Sure, or you could use a private closure variable. The principle is the same.

Comment: yeah, I just pointed out the static "keyword" as it is generally the way to handle this kind of singleton in most languages ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as comfortable, but you might also use a proxy:

```
function wrapped() {};

const testFunc = new Proxy(wrapped, {
    maxInstances: 3,
    instances: 0,
    construct: function (target, argumentsList, newTarget) {
        if (this.instances >= this.maxInstances) {
            throw new Error('Ran out of instances...');
        }
        this.instances++;
        return new wrapped();
    }
});

new testFunc();
new testFunc();
new testFunc();
new testFunc(); // throws
```

The proxy might be returned by a e.g. `allowMaxInstances` function which would allow reusing this pattern.

Or you can use a Singleton pattern (similar to the answer of @melpomene):

```
const TestFunc = (function () {
    const maxInstances = 3;
    let instances;

    function createInstance() {
        const object = new Object('I am new...');
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (instances < maxInstances) {
                return createInstance();
            }
            throw new Error('Run out of instances...');
        }
    };
})();

TestFunc.getInstance();
TestFunc.getInstance();
TestFunc.getInstance();
TestFunc.getInstance(); // throws
```